# Regex find and replace between <div class="customclass"> and </div> tag

Tags: regex

I cant find anywhere a working regex expression to find and replace the text between the div tags

So there is this html where i want to select everything between the `<div class="info">` and `</div>` tag and replace it with some other texts

```
<div class="extraUserInfo">
        <p>Hello World! This is a sample text</p>
        <javascript>.......blah blah blah etc etc
</div>
```

and replace it with

```
My custom text with some codes
<tags> asdasd asdasdasdasdasd</tags>
```

so it would look like

```
<div class="extraUserInfo">
        My custom text with some codes
<tags> asdasd asdasdasdasdasd</tags>
</div>
```

here is a refiddle that all my code is there and as you can see I want to replace the whole bunch of codes between the <div class='extraUserInfo"> and  tag

http://refiddle.co/1h6j

Hope you get what I mean :)

Comment: Can there be `<div`s nested inside `<div class="customclass">` ?

Comment: @Jonny5 nope, fortunately there is no div nested :)

Comment: @mpuria Your regex in your refiddle is incorrect, there needs to be a backslash in the slash in the closing div tag: /(?s)(<div class="extraUserInfo">)(.*?)(<\/div>)/g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's no nesting, would just do a plain match [non-greedy (lazy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)

```
(?s)<div class="extraUserInfo">.*?</div>
```

- `.*?` matches any amount of any character (as few as possible) to meet `</div>`
- Used `s` [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for making the dot match newlines too.

**Edit**: Here a Javascript-version without s modifier

```
/<div class="extraUserInfo">[\s\S]*?<\/div>/g
```

And replace with new content:

```
<div class="extraUserInfo">My custom...</div>
```

See [example at regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vZ2uW3/3); [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Comment: nope, not working :( here is a refiddle that includes my complete code

Comment: just made a quick search and it says it should be greedy [link here](http://i.imgur.com/wnv3GGN.png)

Comment: if i enter the regex without the # it says invalid regex so it should be greedy i suppose :/

Comment: Is this for Javascript or PHP/PCRE regex engine? If PHP try `#<div class="extraUserInfo">.*?</div>#s` instead inline modifier.

Comment: WoW! It Worked! :D

THANKS (y)